# Open a Latex file with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I am trying to replicate using Python the content of the "Tidy Data" paper available [here](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

However, the datasets are available on github as .tex files, and I can't seem to be able to open them with pandas.

To the extent of my searches so far, it seems that pandas can export to latex, but not import from it...

1) Am I correct ?
2) If so, how would you advise me to open those files ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: tex - files are simple text that contains all information for the latex processor to create f.e. a .ps or .pdf. https://github.com/hadley/tidy-data/blob/master/data/billboard-raw.tex is one of the datafiles, it holds the table data that can be parsed by latex. Do you want to know if there is a way to somehow extract the text from the tex-file and create some other kind of data (csv f.e.) ?

Comment: 1) Pretty sure that you are correct. It is easy for pandas to write a .tex file, much more difficult to read from them as they may have different structures. 2) Transform your tex file to csv or json using some tool you like (bash, python, perl, ...), then read the transformed files using pandas

Comment: Thank for your answers ! Yes Patrick, that's what I want to do. In the end I want to start from the "messy" table and manipulate it to get to a tidy format. For this I need the table stored in a DataFrame somehow.

So Corentin your comment is interesting : how do I transform my .tex into a csv file ?

Comment: Maybe a tex-forum would be a better place to ask how to transform tex to .... see f.e. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171325/a-program-to-export-latex-tables-to-excel-ods-csv) with this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171332/146646)

Comment: That's a good start, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this](http://github.com/hadley/tidy-data/blob/master/data/billboard-raw.tex) as example :

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

with open('test.tex') as input_file:
    text = ""
    for line in input_file:
        if '&' in line:
            text += line.replace('\\', '') + '\n'

data = StringIO(text)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="&")
data.close()
```

Returns :

```
    year    artist          track                   time    date.entered    wk1 wk2 wk3
0   2000    2 Pac           Baby Don't Cry          4:22    2000-02-26      87  82  72
1   2000    2Ge+her         The Hardest Part Of ... 3:15    2000-09-02      91  87  92
2   2000    3 Doors Down    Kryptonite              3:53    2000-04-08      81  70  68
3   2000    98verb|^|0      Give Me Just One Nig... 3:24    2000-08-19      51  39  34
4   2000    A*Teens         Dancing Queen           3:44    2000-07-08      97  97  96
5   2000    Aaliyah         I Don't Wanna           4:15    2000-01-29      84  62  51
6   2000    Aaliyah         Try Again               4:03    2000-03-18      59  53  38
7   2000    Adams, Yolanda  Open My Heart           5:30    2000-08-26      76  76  74
```

---

You can also write one script which transform the file :

```
with open('test.tex') as input_file:
    with open('test.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if '&' in line:
                output_file.write(line.replace('\\', '') + '\n')
```

Then another script wich uses pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep="&")
```

Comment: Sounds good, I'll try it with the pew research center's data and see how it goes ! thanks a lot !

Edit : this works. I'll take a look at what StringIO does !

Comment: @BenjaminDubreu pd.read_csv() reads from file. StringIO object simulates a file object so that read_csv works without writing data to disk.

Comment: @BenjaminDubreu But I prefer the second solution and separates the action of transforming your file once and for all then reading the well-formated files with pandas.

Comment: You are right, I'll probably do that. Thank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

1) To my knowledge you can open any standard type of file with python

2) You could try:

```
with open('test.tex', 'w') as text_file:
    //Do something to text_file here
```

Comment: Hi, sure I could, but then the goal of opening it with pandas is to manipulate the data. With opening the file and reading it character to character, I'd need to parse it to recreate columns on something... then I think  I'd be better of replicating the data myself into a xls file or something

Comment: Ho ok I understand now, thank you for explaining it :)

Comment: perhaps, I'll take a look at it, thanks (please note : I am not the one who downvoted your answer, thank you for taking the time ;) )